# Visual stuido 2019 cant find abd.exe

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Xamarin cant seem to find abd.exe ive found it in:

C:/user/me/appdata/local/android/sdk/platform-tools

But when I change the file path to the above I still get the error:

"Cannot find abd.exe in specified SDK path"

Sorry if this is a repost, I tried to find a solution before making the post. Thanks for any help.

[This is the error I recive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI116.jpg)

Comment: I haven't even started making any code yet, I created a "mobile app (xamarin.forms) blank template" and immediately got the error "xamarin.android for visual studio requires android SDK. Please click here to configure."  I have android studio installed, im not entirely sure why its not finding abd.exe.

Comment: So what happens when you click to configure? If there's something about that process that doesn't work or is confusing, you should include that in your question.

Comment: It brings up an "android SDK configuration" with 2 options "use the default installed android SDK" (which does nothing when i slect that option) and "configure an existing android SDK installation (advanced users)" which is just  shows me the filepath visual studio thinks it should be in "C:/program files/ (x86)/android/android-sdk"  when i change the file path  to "C:/user/me/appdata/local/android/sdk/platform-tools" i get the error in that window and the continue button is grayed out

Comment: Did it work before? have you check the path to see if it contains the sdk ?

Comment: Do you need to specify the full path in that textbox? i.e. "C:/user/me/appdata/local/android/sdk/platform-tools\abd.exe" instead of just "C:/user/me/appdata/local/android/sdk/platform-tools"?

Comment: This is my first time trying to set it up, I just installed Xamarin. Also C:/user/me/appdata/local/android/sdk/platform-tools does contain the abd.exe. C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk does not contain abd.exe

Comment: It won't let me specify the full path, It's just a "browse for folder" window

Comment: I added a picture of the "Android SDK configuration" window that pops up

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

so the error says it can't find "C:\user\me\appdata\local\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" but what it's looking for is just the SDK folder, which for some reason on win 10 is installed here:

C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

shortening the file path to the above fixed the issue!

Thanks everyone who helped out! I really appreciate it.